# Old school firefox addon keydown event

Tags: javascript, events, firefox, firefox-addon, add-on

I'm doin an extension by hand, the old school way (without bootstrap, or whatever the new thing is called). I'm trying to figure out how to capture all keydown events, so as to make a new utility for custom keyboard shortcuts.

I already tried adding a window.addeventlistener to the main javascript, but that doesn't work, and i didn't think it would because there's multiple windows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why it didn't work for you, but i added:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function () { alert("keydown");}, true);
```

And it captures every keydown i make.

Comment: where did you add it to?

Comment: To a script inside my browser.xul overlay.

Comment: yeah, i noticed that it worked as soon as i asked. it seems the problem is with passing the event to my custom object, rather than any thing else. thanks man, you certainly answered the original question.

Comment: You can accept it in the tick bellow the arrow. You can only vote up when you get 15 reputation.